# The difference between dependent type signatures and proofs

Tags: language-agnostic, idris, dependent-type, proof-of-correctness

With dependent types, you can either capture function properties in the type signature, like in concatenation with length-indexed lists

```
(++) : Vect m a -> Vect n a -> Vect (m + n) a
```

or you can not use dependent types in your signature, like concatenation with standard lists

```
(++) : List a -> List a -> List a
```

and write proofs about `(++)`

```
appendAddsLength : (xs, ys : List a) -> length (xs ++ ys) = length xs + length ys

lengthNil : length [] = 0

lengthCons : (x : a) -> (xs : List a) -> length (x :: xs) = length xs + 1
```

Is there any difference between these approaches beyond ergonomics?

Comment: Are you aware of  https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/? You might want to have your question moved there, your call.

Comment: @GuyCoder i wasn't. I'll consider it. I don't personally use Idris as a proof assistant

Comment: I noted it because you note `proof` in you question and I am not sure that is really a proof. The experts at the other site would know. Also don't think of the site as ProofAssistants think of it as being for [computational logic](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29/should-questions-arising-from-computational-logic-be-asked)

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference is that, with `(++)` on `Vect`s, the length is statically known: you can operate on it at compile time. Moreover, you don't need to write any additional proofs in order to ensure that `(++)` has the expected behavior on `Vect`s, whereas you need to do it for `Lists`.

That is, `(++)` on `Vect` is **correct by construction**. The compiler will *always* enforce the desired properties, whether you like it or not, and without the user taking any additional action.

---

It's important to note that `length xs` is not really interchangeable with the statically-known size in general. On these data types, `length` is a function which actually re-computes the length of a `List` or `Vect` by walking through it and incrementing a counter:

[`libs/prelude/Prelude/Types.idr:L403-L407`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/a0d9e2bbba8b520e16dd3904fbb679a542e15324/libs/prelude/Prelude/Types.idr#L403-L407)

```
namespace List
  ||| Returns the length of the list.
  public export
  length : List a -> Nat
  length []        = Z
  length (x :: xs) = S (length xs)
```

[`libs/base/Data/Vect.idr:25-28`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/a0d9e2b/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L25-L28)

```
public export
length : (xs : Vect len elem) -> Nat
length [] = 0
length (_::xs) = 1 + length xs
```

Even with `Vect`, the length built into to the type by construction, but the result of applying the `length` function to a `List` or `Vect` is not fundamental at all. In fact, `Data.Vect` contains a *proof* that `Data.Vect.length` that applying `length` to a `Vect n t` always returns `n`:

[`libs/base/Data/Vect.idr:30-34`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/a0d9e2b/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L30-L34)

```
||| Show that the length function on vectors in fact calculates the length
export
lengthCorrect : (xs : Vect len elem) -> length xs = len
lengthCorrect []        = Refl
lengthCorrect (_ :: xs) = rewrite lengthCorrect xs in Refl
```

Using the above proof, we can assert statically, without actually executing `length`, that the result of `length` is propositionally equal to the statically-known length of the `Vect`. But this assurance is not available for `List`. And it's much more cumbersome to work with in general, likely requiring the use of `with ... proof` and `rewrite` a lot more than just using the correct-by-construction type.